# how to log jars used in the compile for gradle

Tags: gradle

I try to log the compileClasspath but it is the empty set (NOTICE the build task in allprojects does the log).  Why is this not logging everything I put in dependencies?  (trying to learn how to fish/debug my gradle issues here as my real issue is the compile is not finding my jars for my subproject).

Notice that the build outputs this following line... with no elements in the array :(

MASTER: I'm building now classpath=[]

```
allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'eclipse'

    buildDir = 'output'

    task hello << { task -> println "I'm $task.project.name" }
    build << { task -> println "MASTER: I'm building now classpath=$sourceSets.main.compileClasspath.files" }
}

subprojects {

    version = 'Developer-Build'
    project.ext.genLibDir = file('lib')
    project.ext.fixedLibDir = file('libother')

    repositories {
         mavenCentral()
    }

    //configurations.compile {
    //  exclude group: 'javax.jms',        module: 'jms'
    //  exclude group: 'com.sun.jdmk',     module: 'jmxtools'
    //  exclude group: 'com.sun.jmx',      module: 'jmxri'
    //}

    dependencies {
        compile group: 'org.hibernate',   name: 'hibernate-entitymanager', version: '4.1.4.Final'
        compile group: 'org.slf4j',       name: 'slf4j-api',               version: '1.6.6'
        compile group: 'org.slf4j',       name: 'log4j-over-slf4j',        version: '1.6.6'
        compile group: 'ch.qos.logback',  name: 'logback-core',            version: '1.0.6'
        compile group: 'joda-time',       name: 'joda-time',               version: '2.1'
        compile group: 'com.google.inject',name: 'guice',                  version: '3.0'
        compile group: 'com.google.protobuf',name: 'protobuf-java',        version: '2.4.1'


        //to be erased soon
        compile group: 'commons-configuration',name:'commons-configuration',version: '1.8'
        compile group: 'org.jboss.netty', name: 'netty',                   version: '3.2.7.Final'

        //compile group: 'org.asteriskjava',name: 'asterisk-java',         version: '1.0.0.M3'            
        compile fileTree(dir: project.ext.fixedLibDir, include: '*.jar')

        compile fileTree(dir: 'webserver/play-1.2.4/framework/lib', include: '*.jar')
        compile fileTree(dir: 'webserver/play-1.2.4/framework', include: '*.jar')
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this works now and am finding the fileTree is not working out for me but the rest are working

gradle :dependencies

or

gradle dependencies

Better answer is here....

[what is the root of the path in gradle when using configuration injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11162432/what-is-the-root-of-the-path-in-gradle-when-using-configuration-injection)

Comment: Currently, the `dependencies` task only shows repository dependencies.