# what is the root of the path in gradle when using configuration injection?

Tags: gradle

I am using configuration injection for gradle and have something like this

```
subprojects {

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'play-1.2.4/framework/lib', include: '*.jar')
        compile fileTree(dir: 'webserver/play-1.2.4/framework', include: '*.jar')
    }
}
```

My directory structure is

```
project
  subproject1
  subrpoject2
```

I run the command

gradle subproject1:dependencies and it is EMPTY :( :(

soooo, what should the relative file paths be so that this works????

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, the `dependencies` task only shows repository dependencies. You can print the files that a configuration gets resolved to with:

task log << {
  configurations.compile.each { println it }
}

Answer (score 1):

Also, it turns out that the confgiuration injection, the paths are relative to the subproject so maybe ../ would be needed in some cases I guess.

Comment: Gradle always interprets relative paths as relative to the current project directory. That's why in a build script, one should always use Gradle's `file("relative/path")` instead of Java's `new File("relative/path")`.

Comment: Instead of `"../libs"`, you can also use `"$rootProject.projectDir/libs"`.

Comment: Great! Thanks @PeterNiederwieser